# BackgroundImage problem with my back button

Tags: iphone, button, background-image, appcelerator

I have a concern that the image I attributed back button does not appear I added this statement but it does nothing

```
win1.setBackButtonTitleImage('back.png');
```

here is the code

```
 var ButtonRetour = Ti.UI.createButtonBar({labels:['Retour'], 
                                           backgroundColor:'#ae4041',  
                                           backgroundImage:'back.png',  
                                           color:'#ffffff' });             
 ButtonRetour.addEventListener('click',
                               function(){    tabGroup.close(); });

 win1.leftNavButton = ButtonRetour;
 win1.setBackButtonTitleImage('back.png');
```

you have an idea about the problem

thank you

I found the solution

I actually changed the code for the creation of back button using the following

```
var backButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Accueil',
    backgroundImage:'images/back.png',
    font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:75,
    height: 35       
});             

backButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    tabGroup.close();
});

win1.leftNavButton = backButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that. Note, that I am not sure whether you can use both `backgroundColor` and `backgroundImage`:

```
    var ButtonRetour = Titanium.UI.createButton({
                    title:'Retour',
                    backgroundColor: '#ae4041', // i am not sure whether you can use both bgColor and bgImage
        backgroundImage:'back.png',
        width:100, //set proper width here
        height:20  //set proper height here
    });
    ButtonRetour.addEventListener('click', function() {
        tabGroup.close();
    });
    win1.leftNavButton = ButtonRetour;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but even disabling backroundColor it does not work and then I added the height and width attributes and it does nothing.

knowing that the image and in the root of my application

Comment: That could be the point, place it into `Resources/images` directory and then reference it as `var image = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'images/back.png');`

Comment: yes I did try to put the image in the images folder but it does not work either. it's a bit strange

Comment: I just noticed something. in fact I've got a window that contains five tabs each window associated with tab should contain the back button.

when I click on a tab I notice that the back button really contains the image but is the form's default button that starts above

it's what all this

Comment: I found the solution

I actually changed the code for the creation of back button